# Is there a way to disable Spotify playlist notifications?

Tags: windows, spotify

There is an annoying red thing going on on the top right corner, top of the megaphone symbol, every time someone changes something on any playlist I've subscribed to.

[image: Spotify notification.]

The problem is that I haven't found any way to disable it.

On the spotify forums there are at least [1](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac/Disabling-notifications-about-additions-to-playlists-I-m/td-p/125598) [2](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Windows/New-notifications-how-do-I-disable-remove-it/td-p/105327) [3](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Newcomers-and-Contribution/Disable-Notifications/td-p/147336) threads about the issue, but I haven't seen any kind of workaround anywhere to make it not appear.

Is there any?

Comment: On OS X I couldn't find any way of disabling playlist notifications. It seems to be a feature Spotify wants us to enjoy :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to disable notifications to changes in subscribed playlists, other than unsubscribing from them. You can add comments and kudos to [this thread here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/ideas/v2/ideapage/blog-id/ideaexchange/article-id/8670/page/15#comments) to lend support for the feature, but as of now the request has not been prioritized. Sorry.